# Calculating the measure of the intersection of generally positioned $n$-orthotopes (hyperrectangles) from their vertices

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, volume, polytopes

If I have a collection of [$n$-orthotopes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthotope.html) ([hyperrectangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle)) for which the vertices are given as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how do I calculate the measure (or, let's call it volume or hypervolume) of their intersection?

Comment: Are the edges parallel to the coordinate axes, or are they more generally positioned?

Comment: Excellent question! Generally positioned.

Comment: This sounds hard, then.  I'm not sure how to do it for rectangles in the plane.

Comment: Given that *any* polytope can be represented as such an intersection (a sufficiently large orthotope is just a half-space for all practical purpose), you should probably just ask how to compute the volume of general polytopes (defined as an intersection of half-spaces). I assume that there is a massive literature on this.